# Click is not working after redirecting in ruby erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a sidebar and hamburger menu in my ruby project for navigation when I click on hamburger menu its working fine its rendering new section but when I click on hamburger again it's not working and my URL is also not changing
here is click events listener

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{

  var hide = document.getElementById("close");
  var ham = document.getElementById("ham");
  var open = document.getElementById("menu");
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar")

  hide.addEventListener('click',function (){
    sidebar.style.display = "none"
    ham.style.display = "flex"
  })

  open.addEventListener('click', function (){
    console.log("hell is real")
    ham.style.display = "none"
    sidebar.style.display = "block"
  })

})
```

Here is my html

```
<div class="hamberger" id="ham">
 <div class="menu-line" id="menu">
  <div class="line" ></div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
<div class="cancel"><span class="symbol" id="close"> X </span></div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item"><%= link_to 'Home', '/'%></li>
    <li class="list-item"><%= link_to 'About', '/about'%></li>
    <li class="list-item"><%= link_to 'Contact', '/signup/new'%></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: There is no turbolink

Answer (score 0):

Change window content load for this

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', ()=>{

  var hide = document.getElementById("close");
  var ham = document.getElementById("ham");
  var open = document.getElementById("menu");
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar")

  hide.addEventListener('click',function (){
    sidebar.style.display = "none"
    ham.style.display = "flex"
  })

  open.addEventListener('click', function (){
    console.log("hell is real")
    ham.style.display = "none"
    sidebar.style.display = "block"
  })

})
```